# Do I need a DAB ariel/antenna when installing a DAB radio in an older car?

Tags: audio, head-unit, antenna

I have a 1991 Mazda MX5, currently in the UK and considering adding a DAB radio before moving to Switzerland.

Do I also need to install a DAB ariel/antenna ?

Comment: Aren’t dab radios different for each country? At least that seems to be what I found... perhaps it has changed?

Comment: I think not https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countries_using_DAB/DMB

Comment: Well I wanted a particular radio station via dab radio and it was not available for the country I was in. But good luck.

Comment: Perhaps they did not broadcast that far? Couldn't your radio fall back on FM?

Comment: FM does not go that far neither AM..

Comment: IF available on AM, fine,- if your radio supports it. If not, you can hardly complain that Radio London doesn't broadcast in Zurich, whether on DAB or not :-)  Back to your original comment - it is my understanding that DAB hardware specs are identical - worldwide

Answer (score 2):

No - although you will need an antenna splitter (something like [this](http://www.caraudiodirect.co.uk/autoleads-pc6-536-dab-aerial-splitter)) as the DAB aerial connector is different.

As a side note you'll also want to ensure that the headunit you buy has DAB+ compatibility - most new kit now **should** have it but it's going to be unpleasant if it doesn't and you get to Switzerland where the vast majority of stations are DAB+.